# Double sided printing fails after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: printing, 23.04

I have an Epson ET-2750 and never had a problem printing double sided in Ubunutu. I can print over the network and I can print via USB without issue.

Immediately after I updated from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04, duplex printing would no longer function. All the print dialogs say it is printing double sided, but when the sheets are actually printed, they are single sided.

I even deleting the printer, then reinstalling the drivers from Epson. Nothing seems to work. I get the same results.

Does anybody have any idea if there is a current bug with the latest Ubuntu 23.04 in regards to such issues. Or does anybody have a solution?

Thank you for your time!

Does anybody know if there

Comment: Visit the CUPS Admin page at `http://localhost:631`, click on the Printers Tab, click on your printer. Modify/Configure the printer paper setting to "2-sided, long edge". I don't recall which submenu this is in.

Comment: I've set double-sided settings in the print dialog of the default PDF viewer, in the print dialog of Firefox, in the "Printing options" (does not affect what is shown in CUPS), in the "Additional printer settings" -> properties (affects what is shown as default in CUPS), none of this has helped for my Brother DCP-L3550CDW with the "Generic" driver. Nothing but problems since the upgrade to 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem with HP Smart Tank 7300. As waltinator replied printing double sided can be enabled from printer settings. They can also be accessed from Settings->Printers and then 'Printing Options'

Problem is that 'Printer Settings' is the only way to change between one sided/two sided printing. Whatever I select from the normal printer dialogs doesn't have any effect. Only what has been chosen from Printer Settings apply.

If I select One Sided from a printer dialog and I have double sided selected from printer settings, I do get double sided and vice versa.

Is there a way to get printer dialog work properly?