# Is duplex printing supported in 23.04?

Tags: printing

Any successful updates on the Duplex printing issue with 23.04 ? I simply cannot make my Epson WF-3620 print duplex, and this is regardless of how the settings are changed. I have been been using 23.04 for a while now and have yet to find a way to make either my ASUS server or Lenovo laptop, print duplex documents successfully.

I have removed cups and installed other print managers apps, without success. I have reinstalled cups as this thread suggests, changed the printer setting via http://localhost:631, each time I test out come two separate pages. I have become quite adept at cancelling the print job before the second page starts.

Any updates on a fix for this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [Double sided printing fails after upgrade to 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467812/double-sided-printing-fails-after-upgrade-to-23-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved - it was the paper setting in the printer. If the paper setting is anything other than plain paper this model printer will not print duplex.

I was using a finished paper stock (Custom) setting because this model printer will print more vibrant colors when using mat paper.

Simple fix all good thanks to those who reviewed my question and scratched their heads for an answer it is appreciated. Issue Closed...